# Uploading similar apps on Google Play and App Store

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

We have a company that helps people create apps for their websites, and we complately rely on webview technology, and push notifications.

We use one developer account to upload all our clients apps to both Google Play and App Store

Would this be considered illegal? Are there any restrictions on uploading similar functionality apps (webviews)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because legal questions are off-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question, not about programming as defined by the [help]. Legal questions can be asked on https://law.stackexchange.com/, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Android:** I don't think there is any restriction for that.

**iOS:** You can't do that. As per the [AppStore Review Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#design), you can't upload apps on behalf of your clients. Also if those apps have similar functionality and looks same, apple will reject those apps (I had two web-view based application for the same client with similar functionality and Apple rejected the second app when submitted for approval)

> 4.2.6 Apps created from a commercialized template or app generation service will be rejected unless they are submitted directly by the
>   provider of the app’s content. These services should not submit apps
>   on behalf of their clients and should offer tools that let their
>   clients create customized, innovative apps that provide unique
>   customer experiences. Another acceptable option for template providers
>   is to create a single binary to host all client content in an
>   aggregated or “picker” model, for example as a restaurant finder app
>   with separate customized entries or pages for each client restaurant,
>   or as an event app with separate entries for each client event.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play: you can't do that either:
From the [Google Play Policy center](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/), the [Spam and Minimum functionality](https://play.google.com/about/spam-min-functionality/) section, under "Repetitive content"

> Apps that are created by an automated tool, wizard service, or based on templates and submitted to Google Play by the operator of that service on behalf of other persons are not allowed. Such apps are only permissible if they are published by an individually registered developer account belonging to the user of the automated tool, not the operator of the service.